# Bluemix - error connecting loopback starter with mongoDB compose

Tags: mongodb, ibm-cloud, loopback

I am trying to setup the loopback starter app on `Bluemix with MongoDB`. I have set up the MongoDB instance in Compose. However, when I keep getting a connection error even though I have followed all instructions and can even connect using the mongo shell.

`{ [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' }`

Comment: If you're able to connect to mongo with shell, its likely a configuration error with your StrongLoop application.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: http://www.technicaladvices.com/2015/10/06/deploying-your-existing-strongloop-application-to-ibm-bluemix/

It shows the details of deploying a "StrongLoop" app in IBM Bluemix.

If the issue is still there open a support request directly from your Bluemix console or you can open a new ticket here: https://support.ng.bluemix.net/gethelp/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by using the following configuration format in datasources.json:

```
"mongoDs": {
  "host": "candidate.53.mongolayer.com",
  "port": 10852,
  "database": "SiteRite",
  "username": "xxxx",
  "password": "xxxx",
  "name": "mongoDs",
  "connector": "mongodb"
}
```

NOT using the 'url' key and using 'host' and 'port' with a separate 'username' and 'password' for the database is what seemed to have fixed it.